# How to retrieve data from db and display that data in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

UserLoginController.php

```
public function userLogin(UserLoginRequest $request){

     $input = Input::all();
     $data = User::get(['name','password']);
     // dd($data->name);
     $data1 = \Response::json($data->toArray());

}
```

Now how to retrieve value from `$data` object??

Comment: what do you want to do with that data? Only show it or what?

Comment: I want to match data recieved in `$data` objet with `$input` data. @lewis4u

Comment: You want to check if name from input exists in users table in DB?

Comment: Yes, I want to match query data with input data @lewis4u

Comment: I have tried this now and there is a problem with password because that field is hidden by default, you need to remove it from $hidden array in model, but you really shouldn't do that...can you search the user only by name is that enough??

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/5